# Javascript how to sort an object by key but do not break the order of orginal object

Tags: javascript

Thinking we have a JSON object. What we supposed to do is sort that JSON object by key and do not break the order of that JSON object.

for example:

```
var data = {
  "321":{
          number:26,
          name: 'l',
          took_date: '12/01/1993',
          left_date: '12/24/1995'
        },
  "341":{
          number:2,
          name: 'h',
          took_date: '12/23/1934',
          left_date: '04/19/1940'
        },
  "513":{
          number:7,
          name: 'i',
          took_date: '07/01/1957',
          left_date: '05/01/1960'
        },
  "123":{
          number:16,
          name: 'b',
          took_date: '03/12/1921',
          left_date: '03/12/1922'
        },
  "890":{
          number:58,
          name: 'w',
          took_date: '07/19/2012',
          left_date: '09/12/2014'
        }
}
```

I want to sort this JSON and do not break its order. Sorry for the confusion.

If I use

```
Object.keys(data).sort();
```

It can be sorted by id but its order will be break.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a copy of the original, with the copy sorted and the original left as is? Object properties don't really have a defined order. Do you mean an array?

Comment: Completely unclear.  Provide an example.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).sort()` will give you a sorted list of an objects keys

Comment: json.parse(whatever_json_you_need_to_parse);

Comment: Objects can not be sorted since they do not have order....

Comment: Looks like someone wasn't paying enough attention in class....

Comment: You cannot sort an Object unless it's an Array.

Comment: In short, I think what you want to do, is make data an array and make the keys of the object just a property on each array item. That'll be easier to work with if the order of the keys displayed is the order you actually want.

Comment: Even after the edit it isn't clear what the problem is. How are you trying to use the results of `Object.keys(data).sort();`? That doesn't change the original object in any way, it produces a *new* array of just the keys which you could then iterate over to process the original object in that order. There is no way to "break" the order of your object, because *objects don't have an order*.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the keys of the object, and then create a new object an loop through the keys and assign.

```
var newObj = {}, sortedKeys = Object.keys(data).sort();

sortedKeys.forEach(function(key) {
  newObj[key] = obj[key]
})
```

Comment: Objects do not have order... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: This is essentially creating two of the same objects. You can't create an object with the keys in order. You can keep an array of the keys in order and then just go through that instead looking up the key from the original object.

Comment: @epascarello no they do not, but by creating an array of the keys, it can be sorted and then a new obj created (which was the op requirement anyway)

Comment: Why is it not guaranteed? If it needs to be sorted in a certain way they can use a compareFunction

Comment: When iterating over an object using a `for..in` loop the property order is not guaranteed. (In practice browsers generally iterate in the order the properties were created, but you shouldn't rely on that.)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function numericObjectWalk(obj, func, context){
  var a = [], c = context || this;
  for(var i in obj){
    a.push(+i);
  }
  a.sort(function(a, b){
    return a-b;
  });
  for(var i=0,v,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    v = a[i]; func.call(c, v, obj[v]);
  }
  return obj;
}
numericObjectWalk(yourObject, function(prop, obj){
  if(prop === 341){
    obj.name = 'new name';
  }
});
```